# S3 client reading the configuration file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp

Is there any free S3 client that supports reading AWS profiles from the configuration file (`.aws/credentials`)?

I tried Cyberduck and winSCP but they unfortunately don't have this kind of support.

Comment: are you sure? Cyberduck explicitly says on their website says it can read credentials file: https://cyberduck.io/s3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [help/en/howto/s3 – Cyberduck](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/s3):

> Connecting using credentials in `~/.aws/credentials`
>
> [Download](https://svn.cyberduck.io/trunk/profiles/S3%20(Credentials%20from%20AWS%20Command%20Line%20Interface).cyberduckprofile) the S3 (Credentials from AWS Security Token Service) profile for preconfigured settings.

I downloaded the linked file and it worked fine.

Comment: You are right. My assumption was that if it's not out of the box then it's not there. Didn't know about the profiles. Thanks a lot.